# how to infer .xib file from UINibDecoder?

Tags: ios, uikit

I am currently debugging some `SomeView: UIView`. I have set a breakpoint within `SomeView.initWithCoder`. I cannot find any .xib files named like SomeView.xib. Where is the UI definition coming from?

Comment: Did you add a `UIView` in Storyboard and assign its custom class to `SomeView`?

Comment: I dont know. It is a large project and I just like to know a straight way to determine the storyboard / xibfile which triggered the initalization of „SomeView“.

Comment: If there is a `UIView` with custom class `SomeView` in a Storyboard, text search your project for `SomeView` ... the results should show you.

Comment: There are multiple storyboards containing this view. I was hoping UiNibDecoder would hold more info about the actual storyboard file.